# Java 1.8 - Collections.sort() throws ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, sorting

I'm working on my code and getting ConcurrentModificationException. How can i fix it?
My version of jdk is `jdk1.8.0_361`
Below is my code

```
package net.stroke.modules.render;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.stroke.modulesystem.BaseModule;
import net.stroke.modulesystem.ModuleCategory;
import net.stroke.modulesystem.ModuleManager;

public class Hud extends BaseModule {
    public Hud() {
        super("Hud", "Shows enabled modules and important information", 0x00, ModuleCategory.RENDER, true);
    }
    
    public static class ModuleComparator implements Comparator<BaseModule> {
        @Override
        public int compare(BaseModule first, BaseModule second) {
            if(Minecraft.getMinecraft().fontRendererObj.getStringWidth(first.name) > Minecraft.getMinecraft().fontRendererObj.getStringWidth(second.name)) {
                return -1;
            }
            
            if(Minecraft.getMinecraft().fontRendererObj.getStringWidth(first.name) > Minecraft.getMinecraft().fontRendererObj.getStringWidth(second.name)) {
                return 1;
            }
            
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    public void onRender() {
        Collections.sort(ModuleManager.modules, new ModuleComparator());
    }
}
```

I also tried sort method:

```
ModuleManager.modules.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(module -> mc.fontRendererObj.getStringWidth(((BaseModule)module).name)));
```

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: `ModuleManager.modules` is being modified externally at the same time as you are sorting it. The only way to fix it is to find out what is modifying it, and either stop it doing so, or work out how to synchronize your sorting with it.

Comment: With that said, it seems highly dubious to be modifying the state of the other class like that - what if there is some importance to the other of that list?

Comment: Note: the ModuleComparator is not great at being a comparator, for example it will never return +1

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentModificationException is thrown when you try to modify a collection (like a list) while iterating over it. To fix this I would syncronize ModuleManager.modules.

```
synchronized (ModuleManager.modules) {
    Collections.sort(ModuleManager.modules, new ModuleComparator());
}
```

or:

```
List<BaseModule> modulesCopy;

synchronized (ModuleManager.modules) {
    modulesCopy = new ArrayList<>(ModuleManager.modules);
}

Collections.sort(modulesCopy, new ModuleComparator());

synchronized (ModuleManager.modules) {
    ModuleManager.modules.clear();
    ModuleManager.modules.addAll(modulesCopy);
}
```

Both your if statements are the same btw